# WordPress SEO by Yoast Changing sitemap xml url

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap

I want to change the url for the sitemap xml in seo yoast plugin.

from: http://example.com/sitemap_index.xml

to: http://example.com/sitemap-something-unique-aqw65643.xml

I know exactly how to change it using rewite rule, but my problem is that I don't know if this is safe.

Is there anyone can explain me what will be the bad effect?

Answer (score 0):

Using a URL rewrite rule for something like this should *not* impose any negative side-effects. You are simply directing traffic from one URL to another. There are even some benefits of using rewrites when it comes to SEO but those mostly pertain to your page URLs. Since you are using WordPress, I'm sure that's not the advice you're looking for.

There is thread on Google Support [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033086?hl=en) that talks about URL mapping when preparing to migrate to a new domain. I'm sure some of this might be helpful information for your situation. I would lean toward a 301 Permanent redirect for a sitemap that I was submitting to Google or another search engine.